# State management in overlapping requests in a UI Framework in PHP

Tags: php, frameworks, state-management

I am developing a UI framework in PHP. The idea is very similar to .NET platform. Different php class are developed to render DOJO controls. In short the framework generates Javascript code to render DOJO UI controls on client side. The process is as follows:

First Request:

- URL GET request come to server.
- Server executes the relevant scripts which load the FORM.
- Call render function of each child control (this generates the
  javascript code)
- serialize the whole FORM object and save it to a SESSION file.
- Output the JS Code to client.

Subsequent Requests:

- FORM postback request comes to server.
- Server loads previous state from SESSION file (using unserialize).
- Update the state object with user submitted values.
- Call event handlers.
- Save the current state in SESSION file.
- Render response to client.

The above process works perfect for a single request at a time from same session. **I need to handle multiple requests from the same session at a time.**

> **Issue:**
>
> Let say there are two requests from the same session R1 and R2
>   respectively. R1 takes 10 secs to complete while R2 takes 3 secs. While
>   R1 was at 5 secs R2 comes and update the state file when R1 is at 8
>   Sec. After that R1 updates the state file again after 2 secs.
>
> **The problem is that the changes made by request R2 to state file is lost.**

How the above scenario could be handled in PHP? Is there any design pattern I can follow for state management in UI framework?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a unique key each time the form is requested (GET) and put it into the form as a hidden input field. This is a common practice to mitigate CSRF attacks, so you can also use it to see which form post relates to each GET request. Maybe it'll be the key to your forms array stored in your session.

Side note: it seems excessive to store some serialized form data with the session on every GET request. In most cases your form would be identical across all users. And on the POST you would presumably know what the form should "look" like anyway (although I imagine you're doing this to generalize the form handler).